# Create a texture with a border and an alpha center

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to draw a selection box, when you click and drag in such a way as an RTS game or on the Windows Desktop. Currently when I run this code, it creates a green box with a transparent diamond in the center.

I am trying to create the box with a solid 1px border and a slightly transparent inside.

```
public class SelectionBox : MonoBehaviour {

    public Color borderColor = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);
    public Color innerColor = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 0.2f);

    bool mouseDown = false;
    Vector2 screenStartSelect, screenEndSelect;
    Texture2D texture2d;

    void Start(){
        texture2d = new Texture2D(3, 3, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        // Top Row
        texture2d.SetPixel(0, 0, borderColor);
        texture2d.SetPixel(1, 0, borderColor);
        texture2d.SetPixel(2, 0, borderColor);

        // Middle Row
        texture2d.SetPixel(0, 1, borderColor);
        texture2d.SetPixel(1, 1, innerColor);
        texture2d.SetPixel(2, 1, borderColor);

        // Bottom Row
        texture2d.SetPixel(0, 2, borderColor);
        texture2d.SetPixel(1, 2, borderColor);
        texture2d.SetPixel(2, 2, borderColor);

        texture2d.Apply();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Mouse button clicked
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !mouseDown){
            mouseDown = true;
            screenStartSelect = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if(mouseDown){
            screenEndSelect = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        // Mouse button released
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && mouseDown){
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        if (mouseDown) {
            GUI.DrawTexture(
                new Rect(
                    screenStartSelect.x,
                    Screen.height - screenStartSelect.y,
                    screenEndSelect.x - screenStartSelect.x,
                    -1 * ((Screen.height - screenStartSelect.y) - (Screen.height - screenEndSelect.y))
                ),
                texture2d
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: it will be much easier for you and for Unity (performance-wise) to draw 4 solid 1px lines on the screen than 1 with alpha

Comment: but if you need to have transparency, again, draw 4 solid borders and one image with transparency

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying...

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a working solution, not sure how optimized this is though:

```
void OnGUI() {
    if (mouseDown) {
        var width = (int)(screenEndSelect.x - screenStartSelect.x);
        var height = (int)(-1 * ((Screen.height - screenStartSelect.y) - (Screen.height - screenEndSelect.y)));
        if((width > 2 || width < -1) && (height > 2 || height < -2)){
            texture2d = new Texture2D(Mathf.Abs(width), Mathf.Abs(height), TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

            var fillColorArray = texture2d.GetPixels();
            var size = fillColorArray.Length;
            var absWidth = Mathf.Abs(width);

            for(var i = 0; i < fillColorArray.Length; ++i){
                fillColorArray[i] = innerColor;
                if(i < absWidth){
                    fillColorArray[i] = borderColor;
                }
                if(i > size - absWidth){
                    fillColorArray[i] = borderColor;
                }
                if((i % absWidth) == 1){
                    fillColorArray[i] = borderColor;
                }
                if((i % absWidth) == absWidth - 1){
                    fillColorArray[i] = borderColor;
                }
            }

            texture2d.SetPixels(fillColorArray);
            texture2d.Apply();

            GUI.DrawTexture(
                new Rect(
                    screenStartSelect.x,
                    Screen.height - screenStartSelect.y,
                    width,
                    height
                ),
                texture2d
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the `Start()` method and I now create the texture in the `OnGUI()` instead